# Bullet lists in spoiler tags

Tags: support, markdown

**Test case 1**

> - this list
> - works
>
> !- but this doesn't?
> ! - (notice how I needed two spaces to create new paragraph in spoiler)

---

**Test case 2**

> - this list
> - works

filler text here

> - but this still doesn't?
> - (notice how I *still* needed two spaces to create new paragraph in spoiler)

Comment: [Also on big meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129441/212780)

Comment: Hack, this is still a little off center , can you post what works out best if you try this

Comment: Some of these formatting features are partial to those who know html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SPOILER BULLETS](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_list_test)

Syntax is

```
>! <ul> <li> tag</li>
>!<p>An unordered list:</p>
>!<ul>
>!  <li>Coffee</li>
>!  <li>Tea</li>
>!  <li>Milk</li>
>!</ul>
```

> - tag
>   An unordered list:
> - Coffee
> - Tea
> - Milk

Comment: It's a hack (relevant username?) but it'll do for now. Thanks to both you and @Geobits !

Comment: Is this supposed to have an extra closing `</ul>` tag? It looks much better with it.

Comment: @Geobits , hi, i am still waiting for someone to refine this. I don't really have any use for bullets in spoiler tags myself so i haven't gotten around to refining it myself. If you can tighten it up that would be great.